# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Grades'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting this error `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Grades'.` The list is populated in the controller and not from a model or database.

What is the standard way of populating a list, should I create a (model) class, or add a new table to the database or keep the approach I am using right now.

The dropdownlist populates correctly, the error comes up when I press submit on the form.

The View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Grades", ViewBag.Grades as SelectList, "Select")
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> grades = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "High School", Value = "High School"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "College/University", Value = "College/University"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Masters", Value = "Masters"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "None", Value = "None"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Other", Value = "Other"}
        };

        ViewBag.Grades = grades;
        //ViewData["Grades"] = grades;
        return View();
    }

  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Models.User user, string grade)
    {

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                using (var db = new login.Models.ShareNotesEntities())
                {

                    newUser.Grade = grade;

                    db.Users.Add(newUser);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Do you get this error on the initial page Get, or only after a Post?

Comment: Check out-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129675/mvc-no-viewdata-item-with-key-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem?rq=1

Comment: Because when you return the form, `ViewBag.Grades` is `null`. You need to reassign the `SelectList`. But do not do it as per the suggested link above (i.e. naming the `SelectList` the same as your property).

Comment: Not also `string grade` in the POST will always be null if you think that's what the selected option will be. And why do you have parameter `Models.User user` when you don't even use the value of `user`?

Comment: I do use user, but I took out the code that wasn't necessary for this problem.

Comment: You are not posting the value of the selected item to the register action
Instead of : 
public ActionResult Register(Models.User user, string grade)
Try:
public ActionResult Register(Models.User user, string Grades)

your property name should match the control name

Answer (score 0):

When the post model is invalid (`ModelState.IsValid == false`), it hits the post, but it doesn't get redirected. I'm assuming there's also a `return View()` that you didn't include in the code. You need to repopulate `ViewBag.Grades`.

Pull out the population to a private function, or a model is better if you have it

```
function PopupulateViewBag() {
    List<SelectListItem> grades = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "High School", Value = "High School"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "College/University", Value = "College/University"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Masters", Value = "Masters"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "None", Value = "None"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Other", Value = "Other"}
    };

    ViewBag.Grades = grades;
}
```

Then, call that method from both the `HttpGet` and the `HttpPost` methods (after failure).